# Possibility of flash Math.random() returning 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random

We all know good old `Math.random()`. It returns a random floating point number between 0 and 1.

What I can't seem to find any evidence about is if zero or one is exclusive or inclusive.

I know that if they are inclusive, the probability of hitting either one of these values is seriously low.

But I can't help but wonder if I should wasting an if statement looking for it or not.

In my current scenario zero is not a problem, but one is.

```
var __rand:uint = Math.floor( Math.random() * myArray.length );
var result:String = myArray[__rand];
```

if the 1 in `Math.random()` is exclusive, then I will know that will NEVER be 1, and therefore __rand could never equal `myArray.length` and should always be below it.. But just wasn't sure if I should waste time in some performance critical code if I should account for it.

**PS: The code above is NOT the performance critical code, just an example**

Basically, just 2 simple questions.
1) Is returning one impossible or possible.
2) If possible, is it worth accounting for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.random will return a number between 0 and (1 exclusive). Never will return a 1.

Comment: As noted in Pixel Elephant's answer 0 is inclusive.

Comment: Is what I write, or not?. Between 0 and 1 exclusive.

Comment: 0 in *inclusive* i.e. random() can return 0 while 1 is *exclusive* i.e. it won't ever be returned.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29):

> Returns a pseudo-random number n, where 0 <= n < 1. The number
>   returned is calculated in an undisclosed manner, and is
>   "pseudo-random" because the calculation inevitably contains some
>   element of non-randomness.

So it can be 0 but not 1. You don't have to worry about index out of bounds.

By the way, if this was really performance critical code, you are better off casting the value as int or uint rather than using Math.floor (see [this performance test](http://adrianwiecek.com/2011/01/11/math-floor-vs-int-vs-uint-cast/)).